# Windows 7 Snipping Tool: huge white border around image

Tags: windows-7, snipping

When I use snipping tool the picture itself is inserted into a substantially bigger canvas. (I'm not talking about the 1px border around the area which can be enabled/disabled by `"Show selection ..."` option).

I obviously want the resulting image to be the exact size of the snipped region, not inserted into 9x bigger (white) canvas. Is there a hidden setting for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about cropping a picture. If you are, then open the picture in paint, select the part of the picture that you want, then click crop.

Comment: I don't want to crop it. I just wnat it to be the size of the area I previously selected. When I start snipping tool and press the "New" button it maked me select the area of the screen I want to capture. After selectiing it the resulting picture in the Snipping Tool will be **bigger** than the area I selected. - The tool copies the selected area to the clipboard too. And the clipboard contains the right parts. Just the tool wants to save a much bigger (white) image containing my selection in the middle.

Comment: If you crop it, then use the snipping tool, there will be nothing extra for it to get.

Comment: btw, for me, the snipping tool gets no extra pixels...

Comment: It worked for me too on my previous system (new laptop now). The interesting thing is that the clipboard contains the right region. Though opening up paint and paste and then save is a bit more than just pushing save in sipping tool, that's why I'd like to "fix" it.

Comment: What do you mean when you say snip?

Comment: I open up Snipping Tool (or press the New button if it's already open), the milkish overlay appears, then select the resion i'm interested in. (I use the Rectangular Ship option, but the same large canvas is used on Free-form Ship too). - Anyway it seems like a program glitch, thanks for the comments, the +1 is due. :)

Comment: Now it seems like the tool also saves the right region to a file. The huge white border is just a display glitch (although even the scroll bars appear).